# Google AppEngine with Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

...seems like a mess in Android-Studio

I start a clean project (called it CloudChat), based on this [tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints), which seems like the most current one.

I can add my backend module and start the server for lokal testing.

First problem:

```
    Jul 09, 2014 4:59:47 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.AppEngineDevAgent premain
    SCHWERWIEGEND: Unable to load the App Engine dev agent. Security restrictions will not be completely emulated.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception during cast.
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.clearcast.ClearCast$CasterImpl.cast(ClearCast.java:385)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.clearcast.ClearCast.staticCast(ClearCast.java:252)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.clearcast.ClearCast.staticCast(ClearCast.java:263)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.AppEngineDevAgent.premain(AppEngineDevAgent.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.google.apphosting.utils.clearcast.ClearCast$CasterImpl can not access a member of class com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.$Proxy0 with modifiers "public"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:101)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:295)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:287)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:398)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.clearcast.ClearCast$CasterImpl.cast(ClearCast.java:383)
    ... 9 more

    Jul 09, 2014 4:59:48 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
    INFORMATION: Successfully processed C:\dev\repos\CloudChat\backend\build\exploded-app\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
    Jul 09, 2014 4:59:48 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
    INFORMATION: Successfully processed C:\dev\repos\CloudChat\backend\build\exploded-app\WEB-INF/web.xml
    Jul 09, 2014 4:59:48 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
    INFORMATION: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\Users\USERNAME\.gradle\appengine-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.6\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\dev\repos\CloudChat\backend\build\exploded-app\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
    Jul 09, 2014 4:59:48 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
    INFORMATION: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
    Jul 09, 2014 4:59:48 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
    INFORMATION: jetty-6.1.x
    Jul 09, 2014 4:59:48 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
    INFORMATION: Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8080
    Jul 09, 2014 4:59:48 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
    INFORMATION: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8080/
    Jul 09, 2014 4:59:48 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
    INFORMATION: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
    Jul 09, 2014 4:59:48 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
    INFORMATION: Dev App Server is now running
```

I am not sure, what this exception is about, but my server is running at least.

Second problem:

It seems like the client libraries (which I had to generate by clicking Tools=>Google Cloud Tools=>Install Client libraries) are not added to the gradle build dependencies.

So I had to go in the explorer (cause the Android Studio does not show this directory) and copy the jar file from "PROJECT/backend/build/libs/whatever-backend-endpoint.jar" to my local "PROJECT/app/libs" folder.

After I've done that, my Android Project is missing "com.google.api.client.*" libraries.
Shouldn't they be included in

```
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.1'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.1'
```

(which are included automatically)?

My Question:

Is there a more painless way of creating and testing a basic GCM+Endpoints Project in Android Studio?

Comment: Seems like you might be using an older version of android studio.  You might want to upgrade to a newer one and try again.  Those instructions on github are for the newest version.

Comment: I used version 0.8.1. Since 0.8.2 is out I'll try that again...

Comment: My problem was not the version of android-studio. My problem was that android studio deleted the dependencies from gradle after I added suport-v4 lib using the wizard (ctrl+shift+alt+s)

Works now thanks

Comment: Yeah, I think that's a bug with how the wizard was resolving dependencies and updating the build file, however I think that got fixed in 0.8.2.  Do you still have that issue when adding dependencies using the wizard?

Comment: same issue with 0.8.2

Answer (score 3):

In the question you have not specified the JDK version you use.

The exception seems more specific to JDK 1.8.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.google.apphosting.utils.clearcast.ClearCast$CasterImpl can not access a member of class com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.$Proxy0 with modifiers "public"
```

If you are using JDK 8, try after switching to JDK 7. You can change the JDK location in `Project Structure`

Comment: I confirm it.  I've run the [Basic Google App Engine Project](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction) WITHOUT  Android Studio (only in the command line) and I got the same _RunTimeException_.  I replaced java8 with java7 and all works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem, check your android app build.gladle file. 
Add below line if it not exist (replace "backend" with your back end module name).

```
compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
```

The code will be like this.

```
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
this dependency.
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+'
        compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    }
```